# How do i create my own datatype variable in VISUAL C++

Tags: visual-c++, binary

I want to create my own varaible that hold only two value 0 and 1.i want to create varaible that holds only two numbers 0 and 1 and it would be equal to 2 bits one for 1 and one for 0

Comment: Why aren't you satisfied with `bool`?

Comment: 0 & 1 only requires 1 bit

Comment: As you know bool is data type which is equal to 1 byte.I want to create my own data type which hold two values and equal to 2bits. one for 1 and the other for 0.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `bool` for boolean values.

To force the compiler to use only a fixed number of bits, use bitfields:

```
struct onebit { int data: 1 };
```

However, this will most likely still require one byte in memory.

Comment: As you know bool is data type which is equal to 1 byte.I want to create my own data type which hold two values and equal to 2bits. one for 1 and the other for 0.

Comment: Why do you keep insisting on using two bits where only one is needed?

Comment: What i want to do that.suppose i have only two (byte values in binary) 01000100 and 01000010.i want to make them equal 1 and 0.like: 01000100 = 1 and 01000010 = 0 now tell me how can i do that

Comment: Have you looked at `std::map`?

Comment: Can you please explain me little bit?

Comment: @Gereon: What `std::map` has to do with it?

Comment: @Ajay It appears @user1990615 now wants to map 68 to 1 and 66 to 0, and `std::map` allows to do just that. Since the question is so vague, has no context whatsoever and has changed from the initial "store 0 and 1" question, I can only guess.

Comment: @Gereon, May be, I wouldn't waste a suggestion on assumption! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Though you can use `bool`, bit field in structure, an enum (to restrict only 2 values). But you cannot restrict the memory usage of such type. It will still need at least 1 byte on program stack (or on heap).

So, if you have:

```
struct OneBit
{
   short OnOrOff : 1;
};
```

The size of `OneBit` will still be 1 byte (minimum!).

Comment: ok,Actually what i want to do is that i want compress two binary values.Suppose i have two binary (byte) values 01000100 and 01000010. first compress them as: 01000100 = 1 and 01000010 = 0 and decompress them as 1 = 01000100 and 0 = 01000010

Comment: You should ALWAYS post understandable question. Try this: ask a question, wait for few seconds and read it. Can you yourself understand it?

Comment: hahahahaha I,m actually a 15 year old boy.i am new in computer programming my english is very bad that why.......     i apologize for that